# What's the tidyeval approach of using dplyr::filter with a database when condition is specified as string?

Tags: r, dplyr

I can't figure out how to use `dplyr::filter` with a database when condition is specified as string. `dplyr::filter_` is easy here but is deprecated.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = ":memory:")
copy_to(con, iris, "iris", temporary = FALSE)
iris_db <- tbl(con, "iris")
filter_str <- "Species == 'setosa'"
```

First try filtering on a dataframe

```r
iris_db %>% collect() %>% filter(eval(parse(text = filter_str))) %>% count()
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>       n
#>   <int>
#> 1    50
```

Now try this on the database using `filter_`

```r
iris_db %>% filter_(filter_str) %>% collect() %>% count()
#> Warning: filter_() is deprecated. 
#> Please use filter() instead
#> 
#> The 'programming' vignette or the tidyeval book can help you
#> to program with filter() : https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org
#> This warning is displayed once per session.
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>       n
#>   <int>
#> 1    50
```

Now try this on the database using `filter`. This fails.

```r
iris_db %>% filter(eval(parse(text = filter_str))) %>% collect() %>% count()
#> Warning: Named arguments ignored for SQL parse
#> Error: near "AS": syntax error
```

And this is why it fails

```r
iris_db %>% filter(eval(parse(text = filter_str))) %>% show_query() 
#> <SQL>
#> Warning: Named arguments ignored for SQL parse
#> SELECT *
#> FROM `iris`
#> WHERE (eval(parse('Species == ''setosa''' AS `text`)))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rlang::parse_expr`.

```
library(dplyr)

iris_db %>% filter(!!rlang::parse_expr(filter_str)) %>% collect() %>% count()

#      n
#  <int>
#1    50
```

It returns the query:

```
iris_db %>% filter(!!rlang::parse_expr(filter_str)) %>% show_query()

#<SQL>
#SELECT *
#FROM `iris`
#WHERE (`Species` = 'setosa')
```

Comment: Super! However this does not work with a data.frame i.e. `iris %>% filter(rlang::parse_expr(filter_str))`. I get `Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector`. Any idea what's happening there? Ideally I'd want something that is independent of the data source (works for both, a db and data.frame)

Comment: Oh wait looks like `iris %>% filter(!!rlang::parse_expr(filter_str)) ` is the way to do it. Also see this https://edwinth.github.io/blog/dplyr-recipes/. Ronak  - can confirm and update your answer? I'll keep it open for a few days before accepting. Thanks again!

Comment: @Shantanu Sorry, I missed your comments. Thanks for suggesting an edit to the answer.